# Zoopla API, try to get some values from JSON in swift

Tags: ios, json, api, swift, getjson

I try to get some JSON values from the Zoopla API but that not response like other API, most probably is my fault and i can't see the error, someone can check my code and find out if is something missing?

Regards,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var areaLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var streetLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var townLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var postcodeLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var outputTypeLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var posterImageView : UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var completar : UITextField!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed (sender: UIButton)
    {
        self.searchZoopla("\(completar)")
    }

    func searchZoopla (forContent : String) {
        var spacelessString = forContent.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var urlPath = NSURL(string: "http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/zed_indices?postcode=\(spacelessString)&output_type=outcode&api_key=<api_key>")

        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        var task = session.dataTaskWithURL(urlPath) {
            data, response, error -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil) {
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            var jsonError : NSError?

            var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &jsonError) as Dictionary<String, String>

            if(jsonError != nil) {
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            }


            self.areaLabel.text = jsonResult["area_name"]
            self.streetLabel.text = jsonResult["street"]
            self.townLabel.text = jsonResult["town"]
            self.postcodeLabel.text = jsonResult["postcode"]
            self.outputTypeLabel.text = jsonResult ["area_url"]
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What issue are you encountering? Is it a compilation error? Or does the actual behavior differ from what you were expecting?

Comment: Nothing about compilation, the thing is not working at all, i check all documentation and should be fine, but not response at button click.

Comment: Thank you for clarification - you have a few options to proceed here. First, ensure that the button is actually connected to your `buttonPressed(sender:)` function. Second, try placing an `NSLog()` inside your `searchZoopla(forContent:)` func, or try debugging it. Third, ensure that you're using the `ViewController` instance that Interface Builder created for you, and you're not instantiating your own using `let vc = ViewController()` or similar.

Comment: Thanks Craig for you quick reply, i am trying whit other's url and that urls working perfectly i think the problem is, that URL not send a JSON code...

Answer (score 2):

Here in your URL if you want JSON response from zoopla then you need to specify it by `.js` otherwise response will be in `xml`. So your URL will be `http://api.zoopla.co.uk/api/v1/zed_indices.js?postcode=...`

The default assumed output format in zoopla will be XML and others can be requested using a file extension, for example using a ".js" suffix would produce JavaScript output.